# aws cli: aws ec2 describe-images : looping and reading from file

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-web-services

I am trying to run a shell script to loop thro a list of image-ids to find the meta data

```
#!/bin/bash
values=$(<$PWD/amis_ID.txt)
for value in $values
do 
  aws ec2 describe-images --region="us-****-1" --image-ids "$value"
done
```

Example amis_ID_only.txt

```
ami-11c3b374
ami-3dd32356
ami-ae3222c6
ami-4cdd9b26
ami-21a7e964
ami-c928e732
ami-15add3ff
ami-2b8e3820
ami-fs0dhswe
...
```

When I print $values, it looks fine to me

But then for loop goes awry

```
 "n error occurred (InvalidAMIID.Malformed) when calling the DescribeImages operation: Invalid id: "ami-11c3b374
```

and goes on thro the loop.

I have tried with and without quotes for $value in for loop. Also thinking if the file format is wrong? Please let me know there are suggestions if I need to clean up the file removing special chars, tabs, spaces with sed, awk etc or anything else if I am missing something.
or if this way of looping even possible for `aws ec2 describe`

FYI: running just the `aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids <ami-id>` worked which spit out a json

Answer (score 1):

You seldom want to loop over file contents directly in `bash`. It's slow, ugly...

The preferred (and nicer) way is - for example:

```
<amis_ID.txt xargs -I{} \
  aws ec2 describe-images --region="us-****-1" --image-ids "{}"
```

Comment: Not sure why but still seeing the same error. Something seems to be off in the file, while i have saved it as txt?

     
       "n error occurred (InvalidAMIID.Malformed) when calling the DescribeImages operation: Invalid id: "ami-11c3b374

there is some kind of next line char its encountering. I have updated the question

Comment: try adding `tr -d "\r"` to the pipeline, maybe your file is in DOS format (`<file tr -d "\r" | xargs ...`).

Answer (score 0):

This was a file format issue. My original solution worked or any other solution would work. The file was in dos format.

Here is what I did: open the file in `vi` editor and fixed the line endings with

`:set fileformat=unix`

Thanks for all solutions